# How to manage heavy armor in Eschalon Book II?

Tags: eschalon-book-2

I'm trying to play as a heavy-armor using character in Eschalon book II. My problem is that even though I invest heavily in strength, wearing all that heavy armor really leaves me very little to spare in my encumbrance value, so I can't carry a lot of treasure.

Any tips on building such a character?

**EDIT:** in addition to investing points into strength I use two +3 str rings, +2 str amulet, +2 str belt etc., and I still find it hard to keep up - I feel like I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I've played some more since I've asked this question, and I think I can deal with heavy armor a bit better now. My conclusions:

**First**, even for a pure warrior with heavy strength investment, you can't just pick the best armor around. Instead, I check the armor-to-weight ratio of various armor pieces, and choose appropriately. So if I have two available upgrades for my boots, one weighing 3 pounds more and provides 1 more armor, and the second weighing 9 pounds more pounds and providing 2 more armor, I'd pick the first one.

It's true that if you look at a specific armor slot then it seems like you're missing on valuable armor points, but overall - if you keep upgrading to items with the best armor-to-weigh ratio, you will gradually improve your armor while not overburdening yourself.

**Second**, the ogre's strength effect, which can be obtained by casting the ogre's strength spell or from potions, is very useful for temporarily increasing your carrying capacity by a great margin. If you can maintain it over a long duration, good; otherwise, it's possible to exploit the fact that effect duration is not reduced by fast-travel. Just hoard all the treasure in one chest, and when you're ready to leave take it all back, cast ogre's strength and then fast-travel to the nearest city to sell.